# Cannot communicate with server in Java

Tags: java, sockets, p2p

I am trying to write server to client program but I cannot communicate with the server in Java.

Here is the code block in my main.

```
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    ipAddress = "78.162.206.164";
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
    String randomStringForPlayerName = RandomStringGenerator.generateRandomString(); 

    baseForReqOpp += ipAddress + " " + serverSocket + " " + randomStringForPlayerName;
    Socket socket = new Socket(host,2050); 
    socket.setSoTimeout(100);

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.write(baseForReqOpp);
    out.flush();

    System.out.println(in.read());
```

I know that there is no problem in the server code and all the communication ports are ok.

But I cannot read anything from the server.

What can be the problem?

Comment: You stripped away too much of the real code. `host` is never defined or initialized.

Comment: Are you really using port 0 for you're `ServerSocket`?

Comment: @John: From what was posted, he is only using it to build `baseForReqOpp`. Which is another variable that is not initialized in this code. Which is also important because the string is being append to.

Comment: i m sure there is no problem with sockets

Comment: strings are initialized above the main

Comment: isn't he trying to connect to his ServerSocket with his Socket?? Or is the Socket connecting to another host? It's hard to tell exactly what he's trying to do because of the ambiguity of the code.

Comment: @cerq You might find this helpful/interesting: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Comment: @cerq: But if you don't show us the code that defines and initializes all the variables you use, we have no hope at understanding exactly what is happening when the code executes.

Answer (score 3):

you have to create an output stream before the input stream

Comment: that shouldn't matter, you can have an input stream and an output stream open on a connection and it doesn't matter which is initialized first

Answer (score 2):

Here is some working code with communicating client and server sockets. Hopefully you can adapt it for your specific problem.

```
public class SocketTest {

    public void runTest() {
        try {
            // create the server
            new SimpleServer().start();
            // connect and send a message
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket sock = new Socket(addr, 9090);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject("Hello server");
            out.flush();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("from server: " + in.readObject());
            sock.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // server has to run in a separate thread so the code doesn't block
    private class SimpleServer extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(9090);
                Socket conn = sock.accept();
                // the code blocks here until a client connects to the server
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("from client: " + in.readObject());
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject("Hello client");
                out.flush();
                sock.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To run it:

```
new SocketTest().runTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never work because you don't use threads. In order to *start* the server, you need to call `accept` at some point in your code

```
myServerSocket.accept();
```

this is a **blocking call**, ie the code flow stops until a client connects. But since you can't execute any statement (remember `accept` is blocking?) how can a client connect? This chicken and egg problem is resolved through threads. See Howard's answer for a code sample.

*I don't see any call to `accept()`, so I wonder what your client connects to...*