# java.lang.NumberFormatException for UTF-8 String

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

Here are the steps I've taken to get this error.

```
move_to_send = Integer.toString(b_id); // b_id >= 0 && b_id <= 8

// Send over socket
byte[] buf = move_to_send.getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, ADDRESS, opp_port);
socket.send(packet);

byte[] buf = new byte[GAME_DATA.BUF_SIZE];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, GAME_DATA.BUF_SIZE);
socket.receive(packet);
byte[] data = packet.getData();
move_received = new String(data, "UTF-8");

// Error then occurs at this line
int move = Integer.parseInt(move_received);
```

I am simply trying to send an integer over a socket.  Perhaps there is a better way? I would still like to know why this error occurs, because if I print the string move_received it is a single digit string

Comment: Did you try trimming the string before parsing it?

Comment: And what does `move_received` contain of characters?

Comment: Have you tried to see what does `move_received` contain?

Comment: I feel very foolish.  The trim worked.  When I was printing the string to debug it, I never considered leading whitespace, only trailing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `getBytes("UTF-8")` instead.

Didn't see the comment that `trim` solved it, but still - adding some info.

`getBytes` returns the string in your system's default charset, so this can cause your string to be garbled.

However, since your `String` only contain digits - and digits are within the `ASCII` range - this should not cause the problem you had - since most charsets like `ISO-XXXX` are one byte charsets and UTF-8 represents the ASCII characters using one byte as well.

In any case, it is good practice for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ObjectOutputStream to send the data and an ObjectInputStream to read the data. Then you can send the data in any format, including String, Integer, or whatever else you choose.

It turns out I answered a somewhat related question yesterday, and gave some example code. You might find the example code useful as well. See [Cannot communicate with server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852313/cant-communicate-with-server-in-java/9854461#9854461)